# Invisible textNodes in the DOM without CSS attributes?

Tags: css, dom, textnode

> On a LinkedIn profile, there's a box in the right column for "Notify Your Network:" which has invisible text on the label for the switch. This is not the same as the header with a `?`
>
> I'm regexing the page and trying to figure out how to exclude instances like this, but I don't see any style that should make it invisible.
>
> I've seen this a lot recently, in different sites, and I'm curious what's going on.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `text-indent: -119988px;` for that label.

[image]